# How are overweight surcharges calculated for connecting flights with Spirit?

Tags: luggage, spirit-airlines

I have a flight with two segments booked on a single ticket with Spirit Airlines in a few days and I want to make sure I correctly understand their overweight surcharges. On [their website](https://www.spirit.com/OptionalServices) it says that a bag with 41-50 lbs. will cost me +$30 and a bag with 51-70 lbs. will cost +55$. It's not clear to me whether I'll pay that twice (since I have two flights) or only once.

It doesn't say anything on their website and I didn't find anything online but I experienced unpleasant surprises in the past I'd like to avoid this time.

Comment: You are travelling on a single ticket, 
all you laggages will be charged once and transported/transferred by airlines internally to another flight. (Only if you two segments flights are owned by same airlines company.)

Comment: @Rafee As far as I remember I had the pleasure of traveling with an airline which charged overweight surcharges based on the number of flight segments and not the number of tickets.

Comment: You should contact the airlines. One of my friends traveled from China (2 Stops) to Singapore, except in that case 1 excess laggage. Charged only 1 time. Airlnes : China Eastern. (Sometimes, they are kind of enough that, they will ignore excess of 1-2 kgs. this happened with me with China Eastern)

Comment: @Rafee I tried that without any success so far. That's why I thought that maybe here somebody can help.

Comment: based on my understanding with this link 
https://customersupport.spirit.com/hc/en-us/articles/202096616-How-much-does-Spirit-charge-for-bags-
`is included with your ticket (Bare Fare™).`. I believe, they will charge only one time.

Comment: Ask them on Twitter: https://twitter.com/SpiritAirlines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems Spirit charges overweight surcharges based on the number of tickets, so if you have a flight with two segments you still pay the surcharge only once. (As expected contacting them didn't help too much as they just copied information from their website, however I already took the flight and paid for overweight luggage.)